# Laravel Datatables ajax unable to send a parameter to query

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am using Laravel Datatables. I am successfully in loading data from a MySQL database through a query.
The problem I have is to be able to query the table by month by sending a month number. I am not able to successfully send a parameter containing the month number to my ajax function on the back end. 
I tried many variations but nothing worked.

I get `"Undefined index: month"`

Here are my code snippets:

Javascript ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var month = "<?= $brandData['month'] ?>"; // contains a month number
        $('#accounts').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            type: "POST",
            ajax: '{!! url('brand_ajax') !!}',
            data : {'month' :  month },
            columns: [
                { data: 'brand_name', name: 'brand_name' , className: 'text-xl-left'},
                { data: 'brand_volume', name: 'brand_volume', className: 'text-xl-right' },
                { data: 'brand_margin', name: 'brand_margin' , className: 'text-xl-right'},
                { data: 'brand_commission', name: 'brand_commission', className: 'text-xl-right' },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my ajax function to return data

```
public function brand_ajax()
{
 $month = $_POST["month"];
    $brands = SaleInvoice::select(DB::raw('brands.name as brand_name,
                avg(NULLIF(margin,0)) as brand_margin,
                sum(commission) as brand_commission,
                sum(amt_invoiced) as brand_volume
                '))
        ->join('brands', 'brands.ext_id', '=', 'saleinvoices.brand_id')
        ->where('brands.is_active', '=', true)
        //                 ->whereRaw('MONTH(saleinvoices.invoice_date) = ?', (11))
        ->whereRaw('MONTH(saleinvoices.invoice_date) = ?', ($month))
        ->having('brand_volume', '>', 0)
        ->groupBy('brands.name')
        ->get();


    return DataTables::of($brands)
        ->editColumn('brand_commission', function ($brand) {
            return number_format($brand->brand_commission, 2);
        })
        ->editColumn('brand_margin', function ($brand) {
            return number_format($brand->brand_margin, 2);
        })
        ->editColumn('brand_volume', function ($brand) {
            return number_format($brand->brand_volume, 2);
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Comment: I can't tell where $brandData is being set from the code you provided, but if that's supposed to contain all your parameters in array or something, could you just:

<?php dd($brandData);?> on the page and see what it gives you? Then you can figure out how to properly get the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself. I just added the parameter to the URL string.

`url('brand_ajax/' . $month)`